# does solution of Normalilization causes duplicacy in NoSQL?

Tags: normalization, nosql

[image]

i am currently using mysql as a database but now i have decided to switch rdbms to nosql probably on mongoDB. i have an doubt that nosql removed the concept of normalization from database so in such a case lots of duplicate records were there should be present on database. does nosql solved this or duplicacy in record is part of nosql?

same customer can registered multiple complaints so while using nosql if normalization not in use we need to store whole customer information each time with key. so my databese contains duplicate data.